# why to use accessors instead of plain assignment?

Tags: c#, .net, accessor

why to use accessors in c#.net while we can use simple assignment like

```
  public string name = "Haymen";
```

instead of doing this:

```
 public string Name 
{
  get 
{ 
  return name; 
}
set 
{
   name = value; 
}
}
```

and how this property gonna set or return something since it don't have any way to set anything apparently ?

```
    public class Movie 
    {
      public int ID { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: in accessor you can put more logic, sample checking value

Answer (score 0):

Skeet has [» an article](http://csharpindepth.com/articles/chapter8/propertiesmatter.aspx) about just that! Your case is covered by automatic properties, so you don't have all the writing work.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what your trying to do, you use accessors for a variety of reasons, one of which is to ensure that class properties are kept private and can only be directly manipulated internally.

An example :-

```
private int _myAge {get; set;}

public int MyAge
{
   get
   {      
      if(_myAge == null)
      {
         _myAge == GetMyAge();
      }

      return _myAge; 

   }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use

```
public string name = "Haymen";
```

1. If you know for sure you will never need to debug the access to that variable (i.e. set a breakpoint when somebody reads/writes it).
2. If you know changing it will never effect the internal state of your object (i.e. side effect that you depend on or expect).
3. You want to have less lines to look at and you have met the above.
4. You want a "data only class" for XML Serialization and you don't want to create a lot of code to do the conversion for private methods (at least as of C# 3.5).

**NOTE** That being said, in general, you should not be exposing fields as public members.  See [here](http://csharpindepth.com/articles/chapter8/propertiesmatter.aspx).

Comment: thanks, please check the edited section and help would be appreciated.

Comment: I really hate public fields, except of very, very rare cases of `public static readonly`. Don't use public read/write fields.

Comment: agreed, but is it worth the problems of dealing with all the people that just hate public fields for no good reason.